# When I attempt to live a video in an infinite loop using the ffmpeg command, it automatically terminates after a few hours

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp

When attempting to continuously loop a video using the ffmpeg command with the following syntax:

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i abc.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmps://abc.xyz/.....
```

I encounter an issue where the process automatically terminates after a few hours. The error message includes the following details:

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe
[flv @ 0x55d73001dd00] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x55d73001dd00] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
Error writing trailer of rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/........................: Broken pipe
frame=1812023 fps= 30 q=-1.0 Lsize= 4902934kB time=16:47:41.10 bitrate= 664.3kbits/s speed=   1x    
video:3879605kB audio:944717kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.629512%
Conversion failed!
```

It seems to be related to a "Broken pipe" error during the writing of the trailer, and issues updating the header with correct duration and filesize. The overall conversion fails with a muxing overhead of 1.629512%.=

I attempted to address the issue by incorporating ffmpeg's reconnect command options, specifically using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i abc.mp4 -c copy -f flv -reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 2 rtmps://abc.xyz/......
```

However, despite including the reconnect commands such as -reconnect 1, -reconnect_streamed 1, and -reconnect_delay_max 2, the error persisted, and the issue of automatic termination after a few hours remained unresolved.

I suspect that the problem may be related to network issues. Although I have included the reconnect command to solve this, I have not yet found a successful solution. I would appreciate assistance in understanding the root cause of this problem and any suggested solutions.

Comment: **1.** Try without `-re`. **2.** Try without `-c copy`. **3.** Try streaming to "local host" (to IP 127.0.0.1).